# No internet access to Google apps on Android 4.3

Tags: connection-issues, nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

So I installed 4.3 on my new Nexus 4 and I found out that I couldn't use the play store, gmail app and other Google apps. I tried clearing the cache but it was of no use. All other apps are working perfect and my internet connection seems okay too. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: OP, it was just recently announced and rolled out within the last 48 hours, it might be found on XDA? Question: How did you *tried clearing the cache*? Was that in custom recovery such as ClockworkMod Recovery/TWRP or was it stock recovery? Or another question for clarification - you installed 4.3 - implying you loaded it yes, and it was not OTA upgrade?

Comment: I seem to have a similar network connectivity issue. Did you find a working solution?

Comment: No, I think there is a misconfiguration in the hosts file, which can only be corrected by rooting. I tried rooting it but I failed. I think I'll wait for the new version of Nexus Root toolkit before giving up and reverting to 4.2.2

Comment: Fixed. I rooted my phone, installed Hosts Editor and deleted an entry which was of Google. All my Google apps work!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the .zip version of the OTA I found on XDA. What worked for me was removing the google account from settings and re adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 4.3 one more time from official 4.3 .zip. I had the same and that helped me.